# Why does not sign-in after callback is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to set omniauth to signin with facebook, here is my setup:

in route:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

in app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb

```
def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

In `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
             scope: 'email,user_birthday', display: 'popup'
  end
```

If I click on link: `/users/auth/facebook/` (as I am already signed into facebook account, and there is already a user in db with email like in the email used in the facebook)

here is the network calls that happens:

```
http://mywebapp.com/users/auth/facebook/

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxx&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday&state=xxxxxx

http://mywebapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-8phIgyflA_NgL-9-FTkXxwUv-xxxxxx-xxxxxx&state=xxxxxx
```

Then, the final url in browser would be:

```
http://mywebapp.com/en#_=_
```

without signing in, and without any flash message.

So, how would I debug why won't the user get signed in?

Comment: Did you try to debug #facebook method? (Using binding.pry) for example.

Comment: No, how would I do so?

Comment: Add gem 'pry' to Gemfile(https://github.com/pry/pry). Then in the code after line @user = put binding.pry. Run you application, and watch server, when server execute #facebook method you will be able to see variables in the method. Well something like that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D37ZTlqK_1o

Comment: Thanks, but I could not test face book omniauth locally, but only on production

Comment: Why? You could create fb test app  with own keys for testing on local env.

Comment: Thanks for note, I will see that